# Removing lines with specific word preg_match and regex

Tags: php, regex, domdocument, preg-match-all

```
<a href="link">[BIOL 107 Section 1] Concepts in Biology</a></td>
<a href="link">[CENG 230 Section 7] Introduction to C Programming</a>
<a href="link">[CENG 230 All Sections] Introduction to C Programming</a></td>
```

That above sample is my code.

I am trying to get the `anchors` which does not contain **ALL**. I tried almost everything, looked regex documents but I couldn't come up with something works.

Comment: What is the question here? Remove lines from _where_? If this is PHP, where is the code that does this? Some lines of HTML isn't really enough to go on here.

Comment: Then please show us what you tried. It is however not good practice ([or evil by some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)) to use regexp to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DON'T use regex to parse HTML, use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$html = '
<a href="link1">[BIOL 107 Section 1] Concepts in Biology</a>
<a href="link2">[CENG 230 Section 7] Introduction to C Programming</a>
<a href="link3">[CENG 230 All Sections] Introduction to C Programming</a>
';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$links = array();
$value = array();
foreach($tags as $a){
    if (preg_match('/\ball\b/i', $a->nodeValue)) continue;
    $links[] = $a->getAttribute('href');
    $value[] = $a->nodeValue;
}
print_r($links);
print_r($value);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => link1
    [1] => link2
)
Array
(
    [0] => [BIOL 107 Section 1] Concepts in Biology
    [1] => [CENG 230 Section 7] Introduction to C Programming
)
```

Comment: I marked this as an answer. Do you know how can I get only between [ ]

Comment: Never mind`if (preg_match('/\[[^\]]*\]/', $a->nodeValue, $matches)) {
 $value[] = $matches[0];
}` Adding this solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex:

```
<a\s*[^>]*?>(?![^<]*?All).*?<\/a>
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/U27um9/5)

Comment: Do you know how to get only the text between [ ] and href value seperately?

Comment: Do you mean inside anchors or in general ?

Comment: `[BIOL 107 Section 1]` this part and `link` value. I can get them seperately with preg match but I can't seperate `ALL` this time.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I am trying to get the text [BIOL 107 Section 1] and link seperately in an array.

Comment: In that case you need to refer to someone who knows PHP. I just thought I can help with regex. anyway.

Comment: Can't we get via regex? One regex for the links and one regex for the [NAME] ?

Comment: You can if you want but it depends.